# SELECT distinct with multiple columns MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to select distinct records in my database but I can't get it to work at all. I have tried DISTINCT and GROUP BY but still no luck.

Example:

This is my code:

```
SELECT
t1.room_id as Room_ID,
t1.room_name as Room_Name,
t2.price_date as Price_for_date,
t3.amount as Price ,
COUNT(t3.unit_id) as c
FROM
table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t1.room_id = t3.room_id
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t3.price_room_id = t2.price_room_id 
WHERE
t2.price_date BETWEEN (20180130) AND (20180530)
GROUP BY 
t2.price_date,
t1.room_id  
ORDER BY
t1.room_id,
t2.price_date DESC
```

T1:

```
id | room_id | room_name
-----------------------
1  | room1   | rm1
2  | room2   | rm2
3  | room3   | rm3
4  | room4   | rm4
5  | room5   | rm5
```

T2:

```
id | price_room_id | price_date
-------------------------------
1  |      000001   | 2018-01-30
2  |      000002   | 2018-02-30
3  |      000003   | 2018-03-30
4  |      000004   | 2018-04-30
5  |      000005   | 2018-05-30
```

T3:

```
id | room_id | price_room_id | amount
-------------------------------------
1  | room1   |      00001    | 100000
2  | room1   |      00002    | 101000
3  | room2   |      00002    | 110000
4  | room3   |      00003    | 200000
5  | room3   |      00004    | 300000
6  | room4   |      00001    | 100000 
7  | room5   |      00005    | 350000
```

What I wanted is to select the room_id, price_room_id, and amount with its latest records between the given dates. From the table above I should get the following:

```
 room_id | price_room_id | amount
-------------------------------------
 room1   |      00002    | 101000
 room2   |      00002    | 110000
 room3   |      00004    | 200000
 room4   |      00001    | 100000 
 room5   |      00005    | 350000
```

But what I'm getting is like this:

```
room_id | price_room_id | amount
-------------------------------------
 room1   |      00002    | 101000
 room1   |      00001    | 100000
 room2   |      00002    | 110000
 room3   |      00004    | 200000
 room3   |      00003    | 110000
 room4   |      00001    | 100000 
 room5   |      00005    | 350000
```

Comment: `select (DISTINCT unit.unit_d), ....`

Comment: I have already tried that but still getting the same results.

Comment: You should a valid data sample  .. and the expected  result  .. all of this as text (not image)  ..and add as text the code you are using  and your actual result

Comment: Every single one of the rows you’re getting is unique ie distinct from every other row. You’re hence getting what you say you want, so what’s the problem?

Comment: Uhm. What I want is to get the latest record from each of the record for every unit_name/id which is by their date.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Just edited it. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I don't have the reputation to comment but what @Caius Jard is saying is that each `room_id` has multiple `price_room_id`s  which is reflected in the output you actually received. But the result that you want only has one price associated with each room_id so which `price_room_id` do you want to return for each `room_id`? From your comment, it seems like you want only the most recent price for each room? However, the initial query that you gave us also has some outputs that are not reflected with the example/desired output you gave. For example, `COUNT(t3.unit_id) as c` what do you want this output to be?

If you just want to show the latest `price_date` and `COUNT(t3.unit_id) as c` with only those latest prices you should probably filter by the latest `price_date`:

```
SELECT
t1.room_id as Room_ID,
t1.room_name as Room_Name,
t2.price_room_id as Price_room_id,
t2.price_date as Price_for_date,
t3.amount as Price ,
COUNT(t3.unit_id) as c
FROM
table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t1.room_id = t3.room_id
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t3.price_room_id = t2.price_room_id
WHERE
t2.price_date = max(t2.price_date)
GROUP BY
t1.room_id
ORDER BY
t1.room_id;
```

EDIT:
Okay I think I understand now. I am not really sure how to get the max date from a date interval and I think this probably a super slow query but try this out:

```
SELECT
t1.room_id as Room_ID,
t1.room_name as Room_Name,
t2.price_room_id as Price_room_id,
t2.price_date as Price_for_date,
t3.amount as Price ,
COUNT(t3.unit_id) as c
FROM
table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t1.room_id = t3.room_id
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t3.price_room_id = t2.price_room_id
WHERE
t2.price_date = (select max(t2.price_date) where t2.price_date BETWEEN '2018-01-30' AND '2018-05-30')
GROUP BY
t1.room_id
ORDER BY
t1.room_id;
```

Comment: I'm sorry if I didn't make myself clear enough. I want to get all the latest records between the given dates. And with that dates, I should only get the latest prices for each dates.

Comment: What do you mean by "latest records between two dates"? Can you edit your desired and actual outputs in your question with the `price_date` that you want to receive from you example dataset? It sounds like you are asking for multiple price dates to be returned is that correct?

Comment: I am a bit confused. It looks like there should be only one price for each date so there should be no need to find the "latest prices for each dates"?

Comment: I mean, from my example above, there are instances that a room is booked for more than 1 date `price_date`. What I want is to get the latest price_date that a room is used.

Example:

Room1 is booked for two dates (00001 and 00002). I only want to get the 00002 record for Room1.

Comment: Try removing the Group by and put DISTINCT in SELECT. SELECT DISTINCT... because group by will group every room_id but in your case you just want to get the latest price_date.

Comment: still getting the same results

Comment: it's still giving me the same results

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the Group by and put DISTINCT in SELECT. SELECT DISTINCT... because group by will group every room_id but in your case you just want to get the latest price_date.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (t1.room_id as Room_ID),
t1.room_name as Room_Name,
t2.price_room_id as Price_room_id,
t2.price_date as Price_for_date,
t3.amount as Price ,
COUNT(t3.unit_id) as c
FROM
table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t1.room_id = t3.room_id
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t3.price_room_id = t2.price_room_id
WHERE
t2.price_date = max(t2.price_date)
ORDER BY
t1.room_id;
```